# obtain related posts by tags

Tags: json, wordpress

I'm integrating all posts from another site, and I want to show related posts of one of these posts , **but only related posts of the same custom post type**...

So, when I'm adding these custom posts, I'm adding custom post meta, and I'm saving these like a json. For example:

**meta_key = "post_tags";**

**meta_value = "["tagA","tagB"]";**

But I can't obtain related posts. I'm trying:

```
global $post;
$tags = get_post_meta($post->ID, "post_tags", true); //this is the json

if ($tags) {
    $args=array(
    'meta_key' => 'post_tags',
    'meta_value' => $tags, // how compare with others posts???
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID), //not the same post
    'posts_per_page'=>5, // Number of related posts to display.
    'caller_get_posts'=>1
);

$my_query = new wp_query( $args );

if($my_query->post_count > 0){
     ?> <h3>Related posts</h3> <?php
}else if($my_query->post_count == 0){
     ?> <h3>There is not related posts</h3> <?php
}
```

But it always displays "There is not related posts"....when I have same posts with the same meta_key 'post_tags' (["tagA","tagB"]).

thanks in advance, Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you add a query parameter of `'post_type'` you can return only posts of your custom post type.

Secondly, you could make your custom post type support post tags and then when you integrate the other posts you can just import the tags using...

```
wp_set_post_terms( $post->ID, $tags );
```

IF you still want to do it your way, saving the terms in a meta field, you will want to save the terms as a PHP array not a JSON array. before you save it as meta use the following...

```
$php_terms = json_decode( $original_json, true );
```

... to convert the json array to a php array. then you can run the same query as you have above. The problem is that where you have queried your terms wordpress is expecting a PHP array so this should fix your issue.

Hope that helps

Dan

Comment: I'm trying it, but I can't

Comment: I also just tired with wp_set_object_terms but I'm obtaining wp_error : "invalidad taxonomy", because I'm using a new taxonomy....and I read that I have to register ir first

Comment: I'm thinking in create a new table...only for tags of this custom post type

Comment: That would be a bad idea, you want to avoid making your database bulky and overcomplicated. especially as tags are already a native feature of wordpress

Comment: Yes, I know...I'll continue investigating

Comment: @DanielGarciaSanchez It would really help to know how you are importing the data in the first place and how your are formatting it on import.